# What happens if more voltage hits your mobile phone charger?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, transformer, mobile

I am new here an i want to know that in the country i love AC voltage is 240 volts but sometimes it exceeds the limit. what happens if voltage like above 300 volts hits your mobile phone charger what would happen to it?

Comment: I also love AC. Real FAN. :p If you're lucky you will fry your charger, if you're not you will fry charger+mobile.

Comment: Clean 240V AC peaks at about 340V.

Comment: @Ashan says that it jumps over 300V. If it was under 300 than if the charger is well made than it would continue working. However he has bad AC line and unknown charger.

Comment: If the voltage ever exceeds about 253V, then the chances are you need to get your neutral line fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely nothing will happen. I can't say for sure because China... is China.

People that design mobile phone chargers always leave margin for *errors*. I am not 100% sure how much the margin is, but some designers make chargers meant for 240 V with 1000 V  rated components. Some might use 400 V instead.

It's *very bad* design to use 240 V rated components, because then, as you might understand, things will break if there's 300 V (*error*). People that are working with this most certainly know what they're doing and use *good design*, aka make your design at least twice as strong for what it's meant for.

If you want to be 100% sure that nothing will happen, open up the charger and look through the components and google their ID and look in their datasheet.